# Inner Border on the top of the image

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to add a top border to the image on hover. The border should appear on the top on the image (i mean inside the image on the top) and it shouldn't add additional pixels to the image's width.

This picture below represents what I want to achieve: left picture - image without border, right picture, image with border on the top of the image[image]

I tried to add a border by using hover, but with hover on the img tag - the border is added to the image - and the width of the image is bigger then.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question. We can't debug images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this code in your css

```
    .image {
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      float:left;
      background:black;
      margin:10px;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      position:relative;
    }
    .image:before {
      content:'';
      opacity:0;     
}
    .image:hover:before {
      position:absolute;
      height:5px;
      width:100%;
      top:0px;
      background:red;
      z-index:100;
      content:'';
      -webkit-transition:all .5s;
      opacity:1;
    }
```

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The 'box-sizing' property is important here to ensure it doesn't add the margin size to the div itself, but instead on the 'inside' if you will.

```css
.image {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  background:black;
  margin:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}
.image img {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}
.image:hover .overlay {
  border-top:4px solid red;
}

.overlay {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/21/soap-bubble-1959327_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/21/soap-bubble-1959327_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: But I see that this border makes image shrinking.

Comment: Code updated. See above.

Answer (score 0):

this is still possible. look into the code in the fiddle link below and try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="top-border"></div>
  <img src="yourimagehere">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-container {
  position:relative;
  width:225px;
  height:225px;
}

.top-border {
  width:100%;
  height:10px;
  background:green;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}

.image-container:hover .top-border {
  display:block
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4k52y5kc/5/

Answer (score 0):

If image size are known and can be `(re)`set in CSS, [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) & [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) might be a way to achieve the desired effect.

```css
img:hover {
  border-top:solid red 15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:bottom left;
  height:275px;
  width:500px;
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/275/food/7" alt="bread"/>
```